# Error Object variable or with block variable not set while returning property

Tags: com, vb6

I'm trying to use my COM class in VB6 application. I made some kind of wrapper. When I create object I see message `Is Nothing 1`, so it suggests that member variable is set and it's not null, but when I try return this member using property, then in return line I see exception `Object variable or with block variable not set`. I have no idea how to fix it.

```
// MyComClass
This is a COM class with method Operation

// clsMyCom.cls
Private WithEvents m_myComClass As MyComClass

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
        
    If m_myComClass Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Is Nothing 1"
    End If
    
    Set m_myComClass = New MyComClass
    
    If m_myComClass Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Is Nothing 2"
    End If

End Sub

Public Property Get MyImplementation() As MyComClass

    If m_myComClass Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Is Nothing 3"
    End If
    
    // in this line I see exception:
    // object variable or with block variable not set
    MyImplementation = m_myComClass

End  Property

// usage
Dim variable As clsMyCom
Set variable = New clsMyCom
Call variable.MyImplementation.Operation(...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the method to this:

```
Public Property Get MyImplementation() As MyComClass

    If m_myComClass Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Is Nothing 3"
    End If
    
    // in this line I see exception:
    // object variable or with block variable not set
    Set MyImplementation = m_myComClass

End  Property
```

To be clear, you missed the `Set`

Comment: I didn't know that `Set` is needed in `Property` when object is returned.

Comment: `MyImplementation = <<expr>>` assigns to object's default property if there is one e.g. shorthand for `MyImplementation.Text = "some string"`. The error "Object required..." means that `MyImplementation` is `Nothing` while trying to assign to its default property.